# Converting each Character Row into String using R

Tags: r

Consider the following sample data;

```
text_1 <- c("Test Test Test", "Sample Data")
text_2 <- c("Sample Sample Sample", "Test Data")
df <- data.frame(text_1, text_2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to convert the **text_1** from character to string and add it to a new column namely **string_text1**.

To convert from character to string, I am using the **as.String** function from the package **NLP**.

But, when I apply the code I have created, I get the following output;

```
|    text_1            |   text_2     |         string_text1       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Test Test Test       | Sample Data  | Test Test Test Sample Data |
| Sample Sample Sample | Test Data    | Test Test Test Sample Data |
```

Code I am using;

```
library(NLP)
df$string_text1 <- as.String(df$text_1)
```

Output which I want is the following;

```
|    text_1            |   text_2     |         string_text1       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Test Test Test       | Sample Data  |      Test Test Test        |
| Sample Sample Sample | Test Data    |  Sample Sample Sample      |
```

I would like each row to be converted into a Class of String.

```
Class 'String'  chr "Test Test Test"
```

Any inputs will be really helpfull.

Comment: There is no specific "string" class in R. For now what it looks is you are just trying to copy content from one column to another `df$string_text1 <- df$text_1`

Comment: I would like to convert the each of the character rows into string using as.String() function from NLP package.

Comment: The function `toString` is not in the  NLP package, its a base function in R.  Try `?NLP::toString` and `?toString`

Comment: Sorry, its as.String

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is not in the NLP package, its a function in base R. However there are functions `String`, `is.String` and `as.String` in NLP.

`String` only converts the first element of a character vector so I've used map to get the result that I think you are after.  Hope I've interpreted this correctly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(NLP)

text_1 <- c("Test Test Test", "Sample Data")
text_2 <- c("Sample Sample Sample", "Test Data")
df <- data.frame(text_1, text_2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(string_text1 = map(.x = df$text_1, .f = NLP::String))

df

#         text_1               text_2   string_text1
#1 Test Test Test Sample Sample Sample Test Test Test
#2    Sample Data            Test Data    Sample Data
```